# How to create rules between parent and child work items

Tags: tfs

We are trying to impose couple of rules  on our project , can you tell us if it is possible to do? and if yes where should I start on this?

One of the example rule is

Deliverable can’t be closed with non-closed children.

- This means that even in resolved state a child item would block closing the deliverable.
- This should apply to parent child link types only
- This would only apply to deliverable parent and any type of valid child

Answer (score 3):

There are two ways you can do this.

1. Server-side:
   You can add a plugin to tfs, that changes workitems. A good example would be [TFSAggregator](https://github.com/tfsaggregator/tfsaggregator). It won't have the solution for your specific problem, but I can show you how to change work items on the server side. Shouldn't be a big problem to add your case. 
   The problem with this solution is, that it only changes a workitem after it has been saved. So user will still be able to close the child, but the server will re-open it.
2. Client-side:
   The second solution would be a custom control, which can be implemented in the WITD of your work item. It can be just an invisible control, that adds some validation. You can find some examples [here](http://witcustomcontrols.codeplex.com/). 
   The downside of this solution? You have to install the custom control on every single client that uses Visual Studio and you may have to develop a specific version for web-access.

Comment: Hi Feroc , For server side plug in do returning Action Denied from the processevent method do the trick to disable those changes? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.teamfoundation.framework.server.eventnotificationstatus.aspx#Y0

Comment: No a work item change can't be cancelled on the server. You'd have to do a  compensating action.